# com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found Photo not found

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-contacts-api

JAVA : I am trying to upload contact image using help document given [**here**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact)  . I am getting below exception from  ContactEntry contact = myService.getEntry(contactURL, ContactEntry.class); line. Clearly it indicates that we need to upload photo before calling method, but we are uploading after this. In help documentation, it is not mentioned like that. Does anyone have faced this issue ?

```
com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found
Photo not found

[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:591)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getEntry(Service.java:1352)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getEntry(GoogleService.java:567)
[12:10:25:368][17-08-2015][SYSERR][INFO][42]:   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getEntry(Service.java:1278)
```

Here is my java code..

```
            ContactEntry contact = myService.getEntry(contactURL, ContactEntry.class);
            Link photoLink = contact.getContactPhotoLink();
            URL photoUrl = new URL(photoLink.getHref());
            GDataRequest request = myService.createRequest(GDataRequest.RequestType.UPDATE, photoUrl, new ContentType("image/jpeg"));
            request.setEtag(photoLink.getEtag());
            OutputStream requestStream = request.getRequestStream();
            requestStream.write(photoData);
            request.execute();
```

where photoData is the byte array of contact image.

Comment: Does each contact contain an image already? If not, perhaps the GDataRequest.RequestType should be set to GDataRequest.RequestType.INSERT. The rest of the code should work properly.